# How to show popup window at bottom of the layout in android and aslo should able to access other views

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

In an activity If I click the listview item I shld show alert dialog below the listview....
Even after getting popup window, I shld able to scroll the listview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your view in window manager. The alert view will be shown and at the same time you can access your list view too.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;

windowManager.addView(yourPopupView, params);
```

Comment: If it worked well, kindly mark this as correct answer :)

Comment: How can I make it with custom height?

Comment: params.width = customWidth;
params.height = customHeight; Set your height like this